# Getting this error while installing nifi on mac- HighSierra

Tags: homebrew, apache-nifi

I am using command **brew install nifi**  and am getting error:

```
Error: *Could not create /usr/local/Cellar
Check you have permission to write to /usr/local*
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: So, do you have permissions to /usr/local* ?

Comment: I was trying to give permission. sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local but was getting error : Operation not Permitted. Then i uninstalled home brew and installed it again. It worked

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chmod a+w /usr/local/Cellar
```

This adds write permissions for all to /usr/local/Cellar. To add propagate the change to subfolders, add -R.

```
sudo chmod -R a+w /usr/local/Cellar
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There was some issue with home brew. I tried permissions but didn't worked. I installed it again. Now working properly.